Blazor JSRUNTIME iframe not working with blob
I have this in an private async Task method
await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("Test");

and is working with this :
async function Test() {
    return await new Promise((resolve) => {
        iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.style.display = 'none';
        iframe.src = "https://localhost/order/create";
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);

        iframe.onload = function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                iframe.contentWindow.print();
            }, 1);
        };

        iframe.contentWindow.onafterprint = function () {
            resolve();
        }
    })
}

but when i use a blob my promise don't return anything and i don't know why :
async function BlazorDownloadFile(content) {
    return await new Promise((resolve) => {
        var blob = new Blob([content], { type: 'application/pdf' }); 
        var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        iframe = document.createElement('iframe'); 
        iframe.style.display = 'none';
        iframe.src = blobURL;
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);

        iframe.onload = function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                iframe.contentWindow.print();
            }, 1);
        };

        iframe.contentWindow.onafterprint = function () {
            resolve(true);
        }
    })
}


What does Chrome DevTools say in the console?

@Bennyboy1973 it says nothing, I just reported in VS2022 that with the blob is like the event onafterprint don’t trigger the resolve().

I'm pretty sure this is a cross-content issue, and you should steer away from it because different browsers may handle this kind of thing differently.  What happens if you create the iframe in Blazor markup instead of trying to add it in JavaScript?
